# Nine patch android

Tags: android

i have a problem with 9 patch although i have read the documentation i am not able to understand how it works exactly.If there is someone who could simply explain it to me i would be very thankful.

What i m trying to do is to simply create a 9 patch image from this picture but the result i get doesnt seem right to me.

the images is:
http://postimg.org/image/iefgkcp3x/

any help is wanted.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [9-Patch editor](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) to create a 9-patch. It shows a live preview.

You also might want to read [this guide](http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/).

Comment: i have already sseen the guide and i was able to create a simple image.But when i am trying to create an image with a pattgern like the one i uploaded it seems that it gets all weird and it doesn;t show up so well.iDoes  t work  with a plain color image only?

Comment: I have this result [link](http://postimg.org/image/faxd5zmdz/)